# How do I make all my javascript external with the window onload function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make all my JavaScript external including the onclick for the submit button, I have a commented out `window.onload` function that I can't get to work. When I remove the `onclick="checkInput();"` from the submit input and uncomment the `window.onload` event in the script , my form doesn't work.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong besides being new to JavaScript.I have included a working snippet, just not external, thanks for any guidance.

```css
/*----------------------------------------------
css settings for HTML div exactCenter 
------------------------------------------------*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);

#main{
width:960px;
margin:50px auto;
font-family:raleway;
}

span{
color:black;
font-weight:bold;
}

h2{
background-color: white;
text-align:center;
border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
margin: -10px -40px;
padding: 30px;
}

hr{
border:0;
border-bottom:1px solid blue;
margin: 10px -40px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#form_layout{
width:300px;
float: left;
border-radius: 10px;
font-family:raleway;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
padding: 10px 40px 25px;
margin-top: -2px;
}
 
input[type=text],input[type=password]{
width:99.5%;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 8px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding-left: 5px;
font-size: 16px;
font-family:raleway;
} 

input[type=submit]{
width: 100%;
background-color:#0467fc;
color: white;
border: 2px solid #0467fc;
padding: 10px;
font-size:20px;
cursor:pointer;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}


a{
text-decoration:none;
color: cornflowerblue;
}

i{
color: cornflowerblue;
}

p{
 font-size:16px;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:red;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
        //window.on onload functionload = function() {
        //document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function(evt) { 
        //checkInput();
        //}//end onload onclick 
  
       
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="main">
   <div id="form_layout">
     <h2>Palindrome Test</h2>
     <br>Enter a 10 character Palindrome.
     <!-- Form starts here-->
     <form name="pForm" id="pForm" method="post" >
     <label>Palindrome:</label>: 
     <input type="text" name="uput" id="uput"/><br>      
     <!-- ... all the other stuff ... -->
    </form><br>
    <input type='submit' id="submit" value="Check Palindrome" onclick="checkInput();"/><br>
    <p><span id="eMsg" class="error"></span><p/><br>
  </div>     
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>isPalindrome</title>
        <script>
        //window.on onload functionload = function() {
        //document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function(evt) { 
        //checkInput();
        //}//end window.onload 


Palindrome(str);

</script>
 </head>
    <body>
   <div id="main">
   <div id="form_layout">
     <h2>Palindrome Test</h2>
     <br>Enter a 10 character Palindrome.
     <!-- Form starts here-->
     <form name="pForm" id="pForm" method="post" >
     <label>Palindrome:</label>: 
     <input type="text" name="uput" id="uput"/><br>      
     <!-- ... all the other stuff ... -->
    </form><br>
    <input type='submit' id="submit" value="Check Palindrome" onclick="checkInput();"/><br>
    <p><span id="eMsg" class="error"></span><p/><br>
     </div>     
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wait for the DOM to finish loading before you can query it to find DOM elements and atach events.

- The simplest fix would be  placing your `<script>` at the end of body.
- Another fix is to attach handlers in window onload event ( that's how it works in code snippet below)

In code snippet provided in question the the way window.onload was attached was unclear. Also at the end of script expression `Palindrome(str);` raised error as var `str` is undefined, so i've fixed it.

See working snippet below:

```
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function(evt) { 
    checkInput();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        
      window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function(evt) { 
    checkInput();
};};
        function checkInput() {
          alert('Check input fired');
        }//end check input
    
  
        
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="main">
   <div id="form_layout">
     <h2>Palindrome Test</h2>
     <br>Enter a 10 character Palindrome.
     <!-- Form starts here-->
     <form name="pForm" id="pForm" method="post" >
     <label>Palindrome:</label>: 
     <input type="text" name="uput" id="uput"/><br>      
     <!-- ... all the other stuff ... -->
    </form><br>
    <input type='submit' id="submit" value="Check Palindrome" /><br>
    <p><span id="eMsg" class="error"></span><p/><br>
  </div>     
   </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi I need the <input type='submit' id="submit" value="Check Palindrome" onclick="checkInput();"/> in the form to be external also.

Comment: @BillyPayne  see updated answer and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi Andriy when I remove the onclick="checkInput();" from the forms <input type='submit' id="submit" value="Check Palindrome" onclick="checkInput();"/> the script doesn't work. How do I make all the javascript external including the form input onclick

Comment: @BillyPayne in code snippet above that `onclick='checkInput` removed and it works.

Comment: thank you that worked, changing id to submit1 was the answer

Comment: @BillyPayneyou are welcome :) ! p.s. Changing id doesn't impact that. You can see my code snippet with reverted id  value `submit` and it still works:)

Comment: then it was nesting the checkInput() into { } after the window.onload = () { Thanks again

Comment: is there anyway to remove this post as to not give anyone a working palindrome solution? or edit?

Comment: @BillyPayne you can adjusr your question to create minimal reproducable problem sample

Comment: After i can adjust answer

Comment: Done Thank You very much for all your help

Comment: answer adjusted,   @BillyPayne you are welcome !) Have i nice day !!